# SSIS Import Files with changing layouts

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I'm using SSIS 2008 and trying to work on a package for importing a specified file into a table created for its layout. It will take in the destination table & source file as package variables.

The main problem I'm running into is that the file layouts are subject to change, they're not consistent. The table I'd be importing into will match the file though. I had initial success, but soon after changing the source file/destination it throws the vs_needsnewmetadata error.

Are there any workarounds discovered that could potentially be used here for files not fitting the layout the package was designed with?

Edit: These are .txt files, tab-delimited.
Edit2: Tried fiddling with OPENROWSET as well, hit a security error on our server.

Comment: What type of file is it? CSV?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that said file is a CSV file.

I have just been faced with the exact same problem a couple of weeks ago. You need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Create a stored procedure on your database with the code below (change the 2 "C:\Folder\" locations to the location of your file):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateAndImportCSVs] (@FILENAME NVARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @PATH NVARCHAR(4000) = N'C:\Folder\' + @FILENAME + ''
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(50) = SUBSTRING(@FILENAME,0,CHARINDEX('.',@FILENAME))
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'IF OBJECT_ID(''dbo.' + @TABLE + ''' , ''U'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.[' + @TABLE + ']
                                SELECT * INTO [' + @TABLE + ']
                                FROM OPENROWSET(''MSDASQL''
                                               ,''Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};DefaultDir=C:\Folder;''
                                               ,''SELECT * FROM ' + @FILENAME + ''')'

EXEC(@SQL)


END
```

You might need to download the Microsoft Access Database Engine from:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255
and install on your machine/server for the Microsoft Access Text Driver to work.

Then create an Execute SQL Task in SSIS with the relevant connection details to your SQL server database. Then pass the file name to the stored procedure you created:

```
EXEC dbo.CreateAndImportCSVs 'filename.csv'
```

It will then create the table based on the structure and data contained within the CSV, it also names the table the same as the csv file name.

*This stored procedure can also be used to run through a list of files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Should've mentioned I tried this. I ran into a security error, guessing it's a restriction placed by the DBA. OpenRowSet would probably have been the way I'd go if that wasn't the case.

Comment: @MikeR That's a default restriction.  So-called "ad hoc queries" of the sort that OpenRowSet and OpenQuery allow are disabled by default.

Comment: Are you not able to get the DBA to change these permissions I'm sure they would be understanding!